# How do you get step status in OmniStepInput?

Tags: omnistudio

I'm trying to build a custom OmniStudio Step Chart by following the instructions here:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_customize_the_step_chart_component_18652.htm&type=5

There is a reference on the page to download the OmniStudio files from here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.os_omniscript_readme_reference_24281.htm&type=5

In the html file for the omniStepChartItems_horizontal there are references to variables for the step status values but they return null if you add to the lwc controller

How do you read the status of the Steps in the LWC?  So for example how can we tell that the status of the step is completed, inProgress, pristine and nonpristine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read the status of the Step Chart Items, you need to extend from **ns/omniscriptStepChartItems** where 'ns' is your OmniStudio namespace, for example, **omnistudio/omniscriptStepChartItems**.

You can use the sample code snippet below and build your component according to your requirements:

```
import OmniscriptStepChartItems from 'omnistudio/omniscriptStepChartItems';

OmniscriptStepChartItemsCustom extends OmniscriptStepChartItems {
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('completed: ', this.completed);
        console.log('inProgress: ', this.inProgress);
        console.log('pristine: ', this.pristine);
        console.log('nonpristine: ', this.nonpristine);
    }
}
```